# Why am I receiving a code indenting error?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I'm trying to publish my question, but I'm always getting this message:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I paste my code, then I select the code and then I press the code button. It seems fine and indented in the preview, but I'm still getting that message when I try to publish it. Why is this happening?

### The preview I get of my message

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the whole post? Is that all of your post?

Comment: Are you still using spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: sure, I've just edited my post. @Qantas94Heavy

Comment: no, I'm using tabs, and I just copied and pasted my code from my text editor. @Jamal

Comment: @polska: I believe he was being sarcastic - spaces are preferred for the editor.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I was being serious.  I've noticed that tabs cause some annoying indentation issues, and I've had to fix such code.  Usually when it's a lot of code, I don't even bother.  I still have to do it the slow way.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy , oh, I didn't understand. But actually in the first time I was attempting to correct the problem by indenting myself with spaces in the text editor, so.. :D

Comment: @Jamal: the way you wrote it seems like you're recommending tabs _instead of_ spaces. _Are you still using spaces_ (at least to me) makes it seem like spaces are inferior to tabs.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: No, not at all.  I'll delete that since it does seem misleading.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it, like you said after, you have been notice that tabs cause some annoying indentation issues. Anyway, problem solved, thanks guys :) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably complaining about this line, which you should indent by four spaces (because it's code):

```
successo = 0; erro = 1; msg_erro = "error message..."
```

And this one:

```
Array ( [successo] => 0 [erro] => 1 [msg_erro] => )
```

You don't *just* have to indent something that is your sample code. If you're writing small snippets of code in your answer, *those* should probably indented too.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Problem solved :) .